# Using ruby for scripting

Tags: ruby

I want to use ruby script for installing all the necessary things for a working rails environment.

I wonder how I could run

```
`sudo aptitude install <appname>`
```

and actually see the output generated just like if I ran that line in the command line.

And when I am prompted to type in something, then I can do that.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `system`.

```
system 'sudo aptitude install <appname>'
```

It will return true if the command excecuted successfully, or false if there was an error. All output will be directed to `$stdout`/`$stderr`.

Answer (score 0):

As tiny correction to Adrian, [these forms avoid shell escaping mess](http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2010/07/another-example-of-ruby-being-awesome-w.html) if appname contains any funny characters:

```
system 'sudo', 'aptitude', 'install', appname

system *%W[sudo aptitude install #{appname}]
```